# Bootstrap-Table Get Saved Cookies

Tags: bootstrap-table

I am using bootstrap-Table to display tabular data 
i have used bootstrap-table-cookie.js to enable state save in browser

My Requirement is i need to get these saved cookies (states ) to SQL server and next time user logged in the saved state should be back .

i Have followed the link [BS-Cookie](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/tree/master/src/extensions/cookie#getcookies) tried getCookies method but its always returning as null

My Code

```
  <script src="~/assets/bootstrap-table/src/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/bootstrap-table/src/extensions/export/bootstrap-table-export.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/bootstrap-cookie/bootstrap-table-cookie.js"></script>


<div>
    <button id="btnSaveState"> save </button>
</div>
<table id="tblff">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="RID" rowspan="2" class="hdr"
                data-cell-style="OperateFormatter">REQID</th>           
            <th data-field="DTP" rowspan="2"> DT OPENED</th>
            <th data-field="SUM" rowspan="2"> SUMM</th>
        </tr>       
    </thead>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: initalURL
                , type: 'GET'
                , contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                , dataType: "json"
                , success: function (response) {
                    $('#CRFTable').bootstrapTable({
                        data: response.rows
                           , cookie: true
                           , cookieIdTable: userID
                           , showRefresh: true
                           , showToggle: true
                           , showColumns: true
                        , showExport: true
                        , exportTypes: "['excel']"
                        , pagination: true
                        , pageList: "[10, 25, 50, 100, ALL]"
                        , idField: "RID"
                        , toolbar: $("#custToolbar")
                    });
                }
                , failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
                , error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
        });

        $("#btnSaveState").on('click', function () {
            try {
                var cookieDetails = $('#tblff').bootstrapTable().getCookie();
                alert(cookieDetails);
            } catch (e) {

            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

But result of getCookies is always null.

can somebody give a good example to get cookies values saved by bootstrap-table

Answer (score 0):

You should use it like this: 
`$("#table").bootstrapTable('getCookies')`